# Where does a class derived from CustomControl get its resources from?

Tags: wpf

For the Resources property of CustomControl where does it's contents come from and how can I add resources to it in XAML? Is Themes/Generic.xaml the best place? Do I need to do some kind of resource merge in the code for the control?

The following can load resources on the fly but I think this may be slow if it's called often.

```
 System.Uri resourceLocater = new System.Uri("/Themes/Generic.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
 ResourceDictionary d = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocater);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place resources in the `Style.Resources` of the default style, however the access of those reasources should be limited to within that style anyway. If they are only needed within the `Template` you can also use the `ControlTemplate.Resources`.